# SharePoint Search 2016 "Items with same keyword as this item" result source

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

I'm looking for an explanation of what this result source represents in SharePoint Search 2016 - "Items with same keyword as this item". It's one of the result sources provided out of the box by SharePoint. In my case it always appears in Top Queries by Month report with an empty query text but high number of total queries.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

“Items with Same Keyword as this Item” is a result source that items having the same keyword details as those specified by the query. It is variable so that there is no query text.

Descriptions of these default result sources:

http://mirceyron.com/Tutorial/topic-130/SharePoint-2013-Users-Guide-425.html

This article also applies to SharePoint 2016.

Comment: Thank you Joanna! Does that mean this source is used only whenever search is picking up items with enterprise keywords enabled? I'm trying to understand the logic behind.